# How to add tasks in Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I need to input each tasks in the GCal tab to Google Calendar. The Event Date is "Due Date", the Title is the "Task"

Here is the working file I am currently working on.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tKfA_Y0TvYliq9Hc9z01AZ7Lbxb4hnmLbJ1kqa6VIp0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation on [Calendar.createAllDayEvent(title, date)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createAllDayEvent(String,Date)), it's should be what you're looking for.

Example: Creates an all-day event for the moon landing

```
 var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createAllDayEvent('Apollo 11 Landing',
     new Date('July 20, 1969'));
```

Comment: if i have var task and var date how can I input it to the code?

var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createAllDayEvent(task,
     new Date(date));